# Text displaying twice in different fonts | Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, replit

I am creating a game using javascript on repl.it. I have run into a problem with the menu screen of my game. The title text for my game displays twice in different fonts over eachother. However, if I refresh the window, the text displays normally. What's causing this and how can I fix it? Thank you.

The game: [Game](https://AlmostPong--joyalmathew.repl.co)
My code: [Code](https://repl.it/@JoyalMathew/AlmostPong)

[image: picture of bug]

(picture of bug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)` before rendering your text in your menu function to clear the previously drawn text before redrawing it again.

```
function menu() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.font = "75px Oswald";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillStyle = txtColor;
    ctx.fillText("Almost Pong!", 250, 200);
    ctx.font = "25px Oswald";
    ctx.fillText("space for two player", 250, 250);
    ctx.fillText("c for one player", 250, 300);
    if (start) {
      addEventListener('keydown', keyDown2, false); addEventListener('keyup', keyUp2, false);
      start = false;
      clearInterval(me_nu);
      anim = setInterval(game, 10);
    }
    if (compStart) {
      p1.name = "CPU";
      compStart = false;
      clearInterval(me_nu);
      anim = setInterval(game, 10);
      compute = true;
    }
 }
```

Fixed Code: https://repl.it/repls/MediumpurpleNearMalware

Result: https://mediumpurplenearmalware--five-nine.repl.co

Comment: Thanks! Why was the text displaying in a different font in the first place? I defined the font before filling it.

Comment: It takes a bit of time for the font to load, so it probably renders in the default browser font before it loads your font and starts drawing it.